# Assisted injection error while trying to create presenter

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform, gwt-gin

I already used Gin assisted injection a few times but I'm new to gwtp and I'm facing an error message I don't understand while trying to instantiate a PresenterWidget using my factory, even after reading several posts on the subject...

```
[ERROR] Error injecting @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) java.lang.Integer: 
Unable to create or inherit binding: 
Binding requested for constant key '@com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) java.lang.Integer' but no explicit binding was found; 
Path to required node:
org.moshika.dtp.client.application.book.page.PagePresenter [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenterWidget(AbstractPresenterModule.java:260)]
```

**Context** : I have to display the content of a book on the screen. For the moment I use a BookPresenter with proxy and place and I will try to bind / unbind pages on the fly as PresenterWidget. I don't think my pages could be implemented as CellWidget because I will implement lots of DTP / WYSIWYG functionalities.

**My Module :**

```
public class CommonModule extends AbstractGinModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    // DefaultPlaceManager Places
    install(new DefaultModule.Builder().defaultPlace(NameTokens.SEARCH).errorPlace(NameTokens.ERROR).unauthorizedPlace(NameTokens.ERROR).build());

    install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(PagePresenter.Factory.class));

    RestDispatchAsyncModule.Builder dispatchBuilder = new RestDispatchAsyncModule.Builder();
    install(dispatchBuilder.build());

    bindConstant().annotatedWith(RestApplicationPath.class).to("rest");

    bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();

    bindPresenter(BookPresenter.class, BookPresenter.MyView.class, BookViewTablet.class, BookPresenter.MyProxy.class);

    bindPresenterWidget(PagePresenter.class, PagePresenter.MyView.class, PageViewTablet.class);

}
```

**BookPresenter :**

```
public class BookPresenter extends Presenter<BookPresenter.MyView, BookPresenter.MyProxy>
    implements BookUiHandlers {

    public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<BookUiHandlers> {
    }

    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken(NameTokens.BOOK)
    public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<BookPresenter> {
    }

    static final Slot<PagePresenter> SLOT_BOOK = new Slot<PagePresenter>();

    private ResourceDelegate<PageResources> pageDelegate;

    private PagePresenter.Factory factory;

    @Inject
    BookPresenter(EventBus eventBus,
        MyView view, MyProxy proxy,
        ResourceDelegate<PageResources> pageDelegate,
        PagePresenter.Factory factory) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_MAIN);

        view.setUiHandlers(this);
        this.pageDelegate= pageDelegate;
        this.factory= factory;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
        NavigationVisibilityEvent.fire(this, true);
        fetchPages(0, 5);
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchPages(final int offset, int limit) {
        pageDelegate.withCallback(new AsyncCallback<List<PageDto>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<PageDto> dtos) {
                clearSlot(SLOT_BOOK);
                for (PageDto dto : dtos) {
                    PagePresenter pagePresenter = factory.create(dto.getFolioPage());
                    addToSlot(SLOT_DEROULE, pagePresenter);
                    pagePresenter.refreshModel();
                }
            }
        }).list(offset, limit);
    }
}
```

**PagePresenter and Factory :**

```
public class PagePresenter extends PresenterWidget<PagePresenter .MyView>
    implements PageUiHandlers {

    public interface MyView extends View {
        void setFolio(Integer folio);
    }

    public interface Factory {
        CahierPageJourPresenter create(Integer folio);
    }

    private ResourceDelegate<PageResources> pageDelegate;

    private Integer folioPage;

    @Inject
    PagePresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view,
        ResourceDelegate<PageResources> pageDelegate,
        @Assisted Integer folio) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        this.pageDelegate= pageDelegate;
        this.folio= folio;
}

    public void refreshModel() {
        pageDelegate.withCallback(new AsyncCallback<PageDto>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PageDtodto) {
                getView().setFolio(dto.getFolio());
            }
        }).get(folio);
    }
}
```

It might be a very stupid mistake since I don't see what I'm doing different from all the other posts on the same subject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use assisted injection here, don't call `bindPresenterWidget(PagePresenter.class, PagePresenter.MyView.class, PageViewTablet.class);` directly. Instead, bind only the view: `bind(PagePresenter.MyView.class).to(PageViewTablet.class);`

`bindPresenterWidget` actually calls `bind(PagePresenter.class)`. Then bindings are resolved and since you don't have a constant for an Integer annotated with `@Assisted`, it throws.

If you only ever have one page visible at a time, you can also use a URL parameter to store the page number. Then you can override `onReset()` and update the content based on the requested page. This technique would avoid instantiating multiple PagePresenter and you can get rid of assisted factories.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher. I was really stuck with. Now I understand why but woooh, I was really far from finding the solution. And for the record, nope, I will display the whole book on the screen (or at least using a deferred loading like infinite scrolling), and for what I understand it seems a good thing to instantiate the corresponding PagePresenters on the fly.